# How can I use Flag Emojis in vs code and render in browser Like Chrome or Firefox in Windows 10?

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, firefox, emoji

When I am trying to use Flag Emojis in my vs code windows 10, it's not showing in vs code or any browser. What can I do?

```
<a href=""></a>
<a href=""></a>
```

But it's showing plain text like us and tr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Updating my mozilla firefox the icons are showing normally. And for Chrome Browser I used an extension for icon. Now it’s working fine in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: What extension did you use?